# Saving to multiple locations within Excel via Macro

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post.

I've recorded a macro to save a file to multiple locations in Microsoft Excel and created a button in my personal ribbon to quickly activate it.

However when I activate the macro I get the prompt to confirm overwrite and I don't need that.

I've read other solutions in these forums but I'm not sure exactly where to insert the code as I'm not much of a coder myself. Could someone please help?

```
Sub SaveToNetworkDrive()
'
' SaveToNetworkDrive Macro
'

'
ChDir "V:\#E902MS"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="V:\#E902MS\Greyson's Excel Log.xls", _
    FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
ChDir "C:\Users\E902MS\Desktop"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\E902MS\Desktop\Greyson's Excel Log.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
    Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Things to try (I've not tested this):  You could either delete the existing workbook (with an error check in case it is not present), or use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: Placing `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the code should solve it. This will overwrite the existing workbook each time (assuming you want that anyway).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman and Ron, that worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use FileCopy instead of save as.  FileCopy will automatically overwrite the destination file.  The On Error Resume next will stop the program from crashing if the worksheet in the copy-to location is currently in use, however this will prevent it from getting overwritten as well.

EDIT:  Added save before copy.

```
Thisworkbook.Save
On Error Resume Next
    FileCopy Application.ThisWorkbook.fullname, "C:\folder\" & Application.ThisWorkbook.Name
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I used the more simple Application.DisplayAlerts function instead, but I appreciate your answer. Thank you!